# Google Workspace Add On HomepageTrigger fires in Google Sheets when changing tabs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

I am developing a Google Workspace Add On on Google Sheets. I've set the manifest file in appscript.json as below. Weirdly, homepageTrigger is fired when I change tab in a Google Sheet, so my card interface effectively reloads. I've tested this with the sample add-on code that Google provides here: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/navigation and am still seeing the issue. Below is the full appscript.json manifest code:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
        "libraryId": "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF",
        "version": "40"
      }
    ],
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "urlFetchWhitelist": ["https://api.getpickaxe.com/"],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Pickaxe",
      "logoUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/HgnvcNx/Lead-Search-Icon-Active-1.png",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#7541EE",
        "secondaryColor": "#7541EE"
      }
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the onHomepage function - simply calling the sample code referenced on this link:https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/navigation

```
function onHomepage() {

  return createNavigationCard();

    };
```

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the whole minimal code to produce an add on to test this?

Comment: @Aerials added code and more context in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: This could be related to the library you are loading. Did you test the behavior without the library?

Comment: I did just now and it seems like the Google oAuth library (ID 1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF) is causing this to happen. Unsure what the best move is though... as this is Google's own oAuth library.

Comment: Maybe the last comment on this issue can shed some light for you? https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/issues/208